# Help with 2 C macros

Tags: c, macros, struct

I've defined 2 macros:

```
#define HCL_CLASS(TYPE) typedef struct TYPE { \
                          HCLUInt rc; \
                          void (*dealloc)(TYPE*);

#define HCL_CLASS_END(TYPE) } TYPE; \
TYPE * TYPE##Alloc() { TYPE *ptr = (TYPE *)malloc(sizeof(TYPE)); if (ptr != NULL) ptr->rc = 1; return ptr; }
```

The purpose of these macros is to create a C struct with some predefined members (retain count and deallocator) function and automatically create an allocator function.

Now, when I use these macros as this:

```
HCL_CLASS(Dummy)
int whatever;
HCL_CLASS_END(Dummy)
```

they get expanded into this (taken directly from XCode):

```
typedef struct Dummy { HCLUInt rc; void (*dealloc)(Dummy*);

int whatever;

} Dummy; Dummy * DummyAlloc() { Dummy *ptr = (Dummy *)malloc(sizeof(Dummy)); if (ptr != ((void *)0)) ptr->rc = 1; return ptr; }
```

And when I try to compile this, I get two errors:

- "Expected ')' before '*' token" on line which calls HCL_CLASS
- "Expected ';' before 'int'" on line which declares the int struct member

I cannot see a reason for these errors. I'd be grateful if you'd help me find it. Thanks.

Comment: Just a general style type, do not cast malloc(). Doing so can hide potential problems by doing so. For instance, assume you forget to include stdlib.h, therefore malloc() is assumed to return int. If sizeof(int) and sizeof(Dummy) aren't the same size, you can imagine the breakage that will ensue. The only time you'd have to cast is if you're mixing with C++ where not doing so will result in an error. C is perfectly happy without the cast, since malloc returns a pointer to something, not anything in particular.

Comment: you mean sizeof(Dummy *) but I +1 you for being correct in general.

Comment: Yes I do, key didn't depress, my error :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to use the struct as the parameter to `dealloc`, not the typedef:

```
#define HCL_CLASS(TYPE) typedef struct _##TYPE { \
                          HCLUInt rc; \
                          void (*dealloc)(struct _##TYPE*);  
                       /* use struct here ^^^^^^, not the typedef */

#define HCL_CLASS_END(TYPE) } TYPE; \
TYPE * TYPE##Alloc() { TYPE *ptr = (TYPE *)malloc(sizeof(TYPE));\
                       if (ptr != NULL) ptr->rc = 1; return ptr; }
```

This is because the typedef isn't complete where you declare `dealloc`.

Also, in C++ your struct name and typedef must not collide.  So I added an underscore to the struct name via `_##TYPE`.

Comment: Thanks, that helped. I'll accept this answer as correct as soon as stackoverflow lets me do so :)

Comment: Yay glad to hear it.  If you are using a very strict compiler in C mode you will have to distinguish the struct name from the typedef name, also.

Comment: Actually, the struct and typedef names *can* 'collide' in C, though i'm fairly sure *C++* requires them to be distinct.

Comment: @David X You are correct, I had the reversed.  Editted for posterity.